# double discount in percent

Tags: php, discount

I have a script for calculating discounts in percent, then I want to add a second discount, what is the script formula?

```
<td>Rp<?= number_format((($r->jual * $r->jumlah) - ($r->jual*$r->jumlah*$r->diskon/100)) ?? 0);?>,-</td>
```

This works for the first discount, how to calculate the second discount

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from repeating what you've written so far? Also, keep in mind that discounts should not be calculated within a template, as this should not be a logic that is part of the view

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

**Example**

```
    function finalDiscount($_originalPrice_of_one_quantity,$quantity,$_firstDiscountPercentage,$_secondDiscountPercentage){

        $_originalPrice = $_originalPrice_of_one_quantity*$quantity;

        // Calculate the final discounted price
        $_finalDiscountedPrice = $_originalPrice * (1 - ($_firstDiscountPercentage / 100)) * (1 - ($_secondDiscountPercentage / 100));

       
        return $_finalDiscountedPrice;


}

finalDiscount(3500,2,10,10); 

//parameter 1 : price of product of 1 quantity
//parameter 2 : quantity of product
//parameter 3 : first discount percentage
//parameter 4 : second discount percentage
```

**Notes : Put above function in your code and just call this function in td by passing argument as above said.**

Comment: hello, thanks for help but the results are still wrong, they are even bigger

Comment: I have checked three times, the results are not wrong. $_finalDiscountedPrice variable value is your result.

Comment: I have tried the formula you gave, the result is bigger, I entered the original price 3500, qty 2, first discount 10% second discount 10%, the result is 11340, it should be 5670

Comment: I tried with the value given by you and I am getting the result 5670.

Comment: I have edited the above code as per the value given by you. Copy this code in a test file and check whether you are getting your desired result.

Comment: This script is the same as the script I made too, what I mean is the explanation of the formula with a discount of 2 without creating a new variable,
This is an example of the first discount and this is how it works, what if it goes straight to the second discount
<td>Rp<?= number_format((($r->sell * $r->amount) - ($r->sell*$r->amount*$r->discount/100)) ?? 0) ;?>,-</td>

Comment: I have just edited the above code, follow the notes given in it.